# How to remotely unjoin and rejoin a computer from a domain?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

May I unjoin and rejoin of a remote(physical) system from an another(also a physical) system, if both the system are in same domains(let say contoso.com)

Can I use this cmdline for this:

```
netdom remove %systemname% /domain:contoso.com /USER:contoso.comt\%username% /Password:%password%
netdom join %systemname% /domain:contoso.com /USER:contoso.com\%username% /Password:%password%
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: What I am syaing is: Can I rejoin a remote(physical) system from an another(also a physical) system, if both the system are in same domains(let say contoso.com) ?

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell commands for this would be:

```
Remove-Computer -ComputerName "Computer01" -UnjoinDomaincredential "Domain01\Admin01" -PassThru -Verbose -Restart

Add-Computer -ComputerName "Computer01" -LocalCredential "Computer01\Administrator" -DomainName "Domain01" -Credential "Domain01\Admin01" -Force -Verbose -Restart
```

Comment: What I am syaing is: Can I rejoin a remote(physical) system from an another(also a physical) system, if both the system are in same domains(let say contoso.com) ?

Answer (score 0):

you could probably do the windows equivalent of SSH and:

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName targetcomputer.domain.local -Credential domain\user

and then issue the commands remotely.

Otherwise, As long as DNS and a local admin account are good you could probably do something like:

1. $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName targetcomputer.domain.local -credentials domain\username
2. Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Remove-Computer -ComputerName "Computer01" -UnjoinDomaincredential "Domain01\Admin01" -PassThru -Verbose -Restart }
3. $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName targetcomputer.domain.local -credentials domain\username
4. Add-Computer -ComputerName "Computer01" -LocalCredential "Computer01\Administrator" -DomainName "Domain01" -Credential "Domain01\Admin01" -Force -Verbose -Restart

food for thought!